# Clear difference between /reset_world and /reset_simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, rosservice

**What is the clear difference between /reset_simulation and /reset_world.** I initially was using /reset_simulation to reset the state of my environment periodically (in the context of RL).

This worked well until I added the functionality of deleting and spawning a new goal model when. From my observation the physical location of the model seems to "glitch". I understand that it has something to do with my condition to when I respawn (/delete_entity , /spawn_entity) the model. But it is clear that I am misunderstanding the process of /reset_simulation.

Often the model is just is not present in the gazebo world when it should be. I guess this could be /reset_simulation resetting the state of gazebo to when the model was not spawned.

I then looked into /reset_world which I believe is the better use case. But it doesn't work well with the slam_toolbox which is a crucial component of my package. The slam_toolbox complains about out of data TF frames (or something to that effect).

**So to summarise I'm looking for clarification on the two services. The /reset ... service that I'm looking for is more to reset the robots to their original position in the world.**

Currently using ROS2 Humble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *seems* to be a duplicate of [difference between reset_simulation and reset_world](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/24566/difference-between-reset_simulation-and-reset_world/), which has (apparently) been migrated here, but I can not locate it<sup>1</sup>.

The answer to that question states:

> These services correspond to the options under Edit in the GUI:
>
> - /gazebo/reset_world <-> Edit > Reset Model Poses
> - /gazebo/reset_simulation <-> Edit > Reset World

From the linked [Beginner: GUI - User interface](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_b2&cat=), under the section [The Menu](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_b2&cat=#TheMenu), there is a little more information:

[image: Menu options]

In text form:

- Reset Model Poses (Reset models to original poses; do not reset time)
- Reset world (Reset everything in world; reset time)

So, the resetting of the time seems to be the major difference.

---

<sup>1</sup> See meta question, [Has answers.gazebosim.org also been migrated to here?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/9176)

Comment: What confused me about /reset_simulation was that If I spawned a model in and then despawned it, subsequent calls to /reset_simulation, would undo the changes either causing the model to despawn when I want to spawned or spawn it when I want it despawned.  /reset_world is the correct use case I found but it breaks most ROS2 packages, so I opted for /set_entity_state. Thanks for your answer